# How to display a SQL Server Report in a .net webpart for SharePoint?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, web-parts

Can anyone describe to me the exact steps in displaying a SQL Server Report hosted on the report server (Remote mode) in a customized webpart? I realize that there is an out of the box web part that comes with SSRS but I want to be able to have already configured webparts that display specific reports available for users to add in their edit site modes. Essentially, the goal is to have a report such as 'Assigned Hours' as a web part itself, and anyone interested in displaying Assigned Hours need only click on Site Actions, Edit Page, Add Web Parts, and choose the Assigned Hours Web Part. No need for configuring a report server url or report path. Also, for certain reasons we would like to continue running the report server in native mode so Integrated mode with SharePoint is not an option.

So, below is a summary of my situation and what I have already tried:

1. Environment is WSS3.0, Microsoft SQL Server 2005
2. I have created a .net webpart and am attempting to add an instance of the ReportViewer control to the webpart. I have set to run in remote processing mode and have extended the abstract IReportServerCredentials class to handle the authentication.
3. I have made sure that the assembly is set to AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers
4. The project compiles fine. I place the dll in the correct wss bin folder for webparts.
5. When I try to view the webpart I get the site error message 'That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.'

I've read things about registering my assembly with SQL Server, which I have tried with the CREATE ASSEMBLY SQL syntax, but that I am getting an sql query error saying that the there is already a reference to another assembly and that it can not find it in the same location.

Honestly, I don't really know enough about SQL Server and reporting services to know if I am close to getting it to work or if I have everything set up completely wrong in the first place. I have made custom webparts before and successfully deployed them to the site, so I know the problems lie in my ignorance of the SSRS and SQL Server. Has anyone else accomplished what I described early before? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using an ASP.NET ReportViewer control in your web part. These controls allow you to customize all parts you mentioned and are fairly easy to use and set-up. The one thing to watch for though with this control would be browser compatibility. Out of the box, it doesn't work too well with Firefox or Chrome. If you wanted though you could attached to the Reporting Services service which would give you the data you want back, then write a template-able control that used that structure to output the data. That option is much more complex, but allows for the format to be defined by the web part, rather than the report.

Comment: I have actually done this already, but I am having issues with connecting to the report server. Basically, I can access the web url fine, but when I set the reportserverurl in the control, then I get the following error message upon viewing the part: 'The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.' I have followed almost all of the solutions I can find for receiving this error (editing the reportserverconfig file, making sure report manager has proper permissions for users)...still can't get it to work?

Comment: Are you able to navigate to the report server by itself?

Comment: Yes, i can view both http://servername/reports and http://servername/reportserver (which is just the folder view). Doesn't seem to connect when I specify the reportserver url in the ReportViewer control

Comment: I encountered a similar issue - the app pool user of the application where the report viewer control resides is being used to try and connect to the report server. You need to grant the user of the app pool browser access to the report. On the other hand, if you've successfully impersonated a user through the use of IReportServerCredentials then make sure the user specified by the instance of that object has sufficient permissions as well. In short, this is probably a permissions issue (I fought with this recently as well, without WSS getting involved mind you)

Comment: Got it working finally! I think the main issue was I thought just rebuilding the assembly would be enough but it seemed I had to uninstall it from the GAC and put it back in there for some reason for any real code changes to take effect? Either way after doing that it just suddenly started working! Pretty sure the issue lied in setting the correct user permissions like you said, Max. Thanks for the advice!